# Mostrar lista de emails com Tkinter

Tags: python, lista, tkinter, email

Estou a fazer um programa em Tkinter que se baseia numa caixa de e-mail. Pretendo, numa janela de Tkinter mostrar uma lista de emails que tem como base um diretorio com ficheiros `.txt` ( que são os emails). Estive à procura de um comando para criar uma caixa e mostrar em linhas os nomes dos txt mas não consigo encontrar. Alguém sabe algum?

Comment: Caixa do género da caixa de entrada do hotmail por exemplo. Mostrar linha a linha como se fosse na caixa de entrada do hotmail. E cada linha corresponde aos emails.

Comment: ![http://imgur.com/I9hv9Lx](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10) Deste genéro, mas claro apenas em linhas sem tanto detalhe e opções.

Comment: Deste género: http://imgur.com/I9hv9Lx. O link anterior estava errado, desculpa.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um widget que se chama `Treeview`, que faz parte do modulo `ttk` (um sub-modulo de tkinter), que te permite de ter uma espécie de tabela onde claramente podes adicionar linhas (ou até mesmo uma hierarquia de linhas (umas debaixo doutras como se fossem filhas umas das outras).

Aqui tens um exemplo que eu tinha criado a bastante tempo atras onde te mostra como remover linhas duma `Treeview`, claramente mostra-te também como adicionar (se não como poderia remover algo que não existe?).

> https://github.com/dossan/tkinter/blob/master/other/howtos/remove_row_from_tree.py

Também podes adicionar "event handlers" a especificas linhas. Por exemplo, se quisesses chamar uma função quando fazes click numa linha, podes faze-lo aplicando aqueles que se chamam "tags".

Se queres saber mais sobre este widget (e como adicionar "tags"), dá uma olhada a este artigo bastante bem escrito e com outros exemplos:

> http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

Nota bem que esse artigo tem código também para outras linguagens de programação que não sejam Python, mas podes especificamente ler código só em Python se o especificas ao lado direito em cima, num drop down menu que se chama "Show".

Existem também outras livrarias third-party que te permitem criar mesmo tabelas. Por exemplo, esta [aqui](https://github.com/dossan/tktable) que tenho como repositório no meu account do Github criada por Guilherme Polo. Mas existem outras, como tkintertable. Se não também poderias criar tu a tua tabela, mas talvez não valha a pena.